# What test to use to compare whether one answer in a multiple choice question differ across conditions/treatments?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

I will have a multiple-choice question after a scenario. I have two treatments, different people participate in different treatments, and in each treatment, they read a different scenario. The multiple-choice question is the same for both groups of people.

My question is which test shall I use to test that the proportion of people choosing answer A of the multiple-choice (consisting of 5 alternatives) in the treatment group is higher than the proportion of people choosing answer A in the control group.\

I think a test of proportions is not adequate because the multiple-choice is not binomial, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Any polytomous variable can be converted into dichotomus one "this vs not-this" when your focus of interest is just "this".

Answer (score 0):

Any test you would use for proportions, such as chi-squared or logistic regression, is fine here, actually! It is binomial if you code it as "Chose A" versus "Did not chose A", and there's no reason you can't do so.